# How get_it flutter package deals with Garbage Collector as it registers all the instance at start

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, package, service-locator

I have a naive question, I  have read about the flutter dependency injection package get_it, it registers all the instances at start like the service locator design pattern, my question is how it deals with a garbage collector and when it frees the objects? Does it store all the instances in memory at start till app lifeCycle?

To be honest, I know very little about Service locator design pattern otherwise I might have understood this package clearly, Now I need your help on how it works under the hood? what if we need to register an instance at run time with some dynamic data coming from API then how can we do that?

Your help will be appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#unregistering-singletons-or-factories), you can unregister a previously registered instance as follows:

```
/// Unregister an [instance] of an object or a factory/singleton by Type [T] or by name [instanceName]
/// if you need to dispose some resources before the reset, you can
/// provide a [disposingFunction]. This function overrides the disposing
/// you might have provided when registering.
void unregister<T>({Object instance,String instanceName, void Function(T) disposingFunction})
```

Service objects are often need throughout the life of an application, in which case you'll never need to unregister.

Comment: does it mean we will make all the instances of an application in memory till app lifeCycle? I do not think so beacause it will take so much memory and garbage collector will be not in use

Comment: It depends. If your service is for example a GPS service that provides location data, then that service may well exist throughout the app life cycle.  If your service (or object) is only needed to render one Widget in your app (eg a local database access object), then you can for instance register it in `initState()` and unregister it in `dispose()` of that StatefulWidget.  It depends on what you use the object for, and it's your choice depending on that use.

Comment: what if I need one same object in three, four classes, then how will I create an object and where so that I can use it in all those classes and then I should dispose it off?

Comment: You register it at the start, use it in each of your classes, and when you are sure you no longer need it you can unregister it.  Again though, typically the object you obtain using GetIt is some service object that - in the example you gave - you probably just keep alive throughout your application's life.  If that creates a memory problem (unlikely, because there's only one instance of that object, but possible) then you need to keep track of how many classes are using the object and unregister when that count drops to 0. Again, this is not how GetIt is normally used.